# string split in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have strings like this:

```
    00123_MassFlow
    0022245_VOlumeFlow
    122_447_Temperature
```

I have to split these strings with `_` using C#. `_` may appear multiple places but i have to take last value.

My should be like this:

```
    MassFlow
    VOlumeFlow
    Temperature
```

How i can achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

```
"122_447_Temperature".Split('_').Last();
```

If you don't mind the extra overhead of creating an array and throwing away a bunch of strings.  It won't be as fast as using `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` manually, but it's a ton easier to read and maintain, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

If your input is in a single string, you can use `string.Split('\n')` to get it into a collection:

```
string input = @"00123_MassFlow
0022245_VOlumeFlow
122_447_Temperature";

var items = input.Split('\n');
```

Otherwise, I'm going to assume your strings are already in a collection called `items`. From there, you can use LINQ to accomplish this easily:

```
List<string> result = (from x in items
                       let y = x.Trim()
                       select y.Substring(y.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)).ToList();
```

`result` will contain the strings `MassFlow`, `VOlumeFlow`, and `Temperature`.