# C# trim string with ip address and port

Tags: c#, string, trim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string split in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207374/string-split-in-c)

Hello guys i am getting connected ip address from socket which is looks like this: >> "188.169.28.103:61635" how i can put ip address into one string and port into another?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I'd use `Substring`:

```
int colonIndex = text.IndexOf(':');
if (colonIndex == -1)
{
    // Or whatever
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid host:port format");
}
string host = text.Substring(0, colonIndex);
string port = text.Substring(colonIndex + 1);
```

Mark mentioned using `string.Split` which is a good option too - but then you should probably check the number of parts:

```
string[] parts = s.Split(':');
if (parts.Length != 2)
{
    // Could be just one part, or more than 2...
    // throw an exception or whatever
}
string host = parts[0];
string port = parts[1];
```

Or if you're happy with the port part containing a colon (as my `Substring` version does) then you can use:

```
// Split into at most two parts
string[] parts = s.Split(new char[] {':'}, 2);
if (parts.Length != 2)
{
    // This time it means there's no colon at all
    // throw an exception or whatever
}
string host = parts[0];
string port = parts[1];
```

Another alternative would be to use a regular expression to match the two parts as groups. To be honest I'd say that's overkill *at the moment*, but if things became more complicated it may become a more attractive option. (I tend to use simple string operations until things start getting hairy and more "pattern-like", at which point I break out regular expressions with some trepidation.)

Comment: +1 "I break out regular expressions with some trepidation" - naw you don't :) Surely you just likely think they're ugly and hard to read?

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but still worth mentioning that this is not compatible with IpV6, for example the localhost address with port 1024 `::1:1024`

Answer (score 3):

I would use `string.Split()`:

```
var parts = ip.Split(':');
string ipAddress = parts[0];
string port = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
string[] parts = s.Split(':');
```

This will put the IP address in `parts[0]` and the port in `parts[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string test = "188.169.28.103:61635";

string [] result  = test.Split(new char[]{':'});

string ip = result[0];
string port = result[1];
```