# Split Name into First name and Last Name

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string split in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207374/string-split-in-c-sharp)

How to **split Name string into First Name and Last Name based on Space** between First Name and Last Name in string.
For examle:
**Input string**: "Visual Studio"
**Required Output First Name**: "Visual"
                **Last Name**: "Studio"

How it can be done in **C#** ? Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string fullName = "Visual Studio";
var names = fullName.Split(' ');
string firstName = names[0];
string lastName = names[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you have to do is split by space, then how about using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
var names = Name.Split(new char[]{' '});
var firstName = names[0];
var lastName = names[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

When looking at your functional requirement, you cannot be sure with just a string split.

Can you be sure that only Firstnames and Lastnames exist in your datasource?
For example, in Dutch we have names like:

```
"Maurice Peterse"  // OK
"Daniel Van Puffelen" // FAILS (Prefix in LastName)
"Marieke Peterse Deijn" // FAILS (Maiden Name)
"Jan Pieter Balkenende" // FAILS (Double first name)
```

Answer (score 3):

For your case, you do not even have to give a separator:

```
var name = "Visual Studio";
var split = name.Split();
```

This gives you split, which contains two strings, "Visual" and "Studio".

Comment: +1 for remembering that the `separator` char array is allowed to be empty (in which case white space characters are used as separators).

Answer (score 0):

use String.split

```
var names = Name.Split(new char[]{' '});
var firstName = names[0];
var lastName = names[1];
```

But make sure with your requirement in validation. Some times the names may involve 2 spaces as well.